# how to change li last anchor color

Tags: jquery, html, css, breadcrumbs

`li` elements are use used to create breadcrumb in shopping cart.
Breadcrumb shows all anchor elements using style defined for a element from site.css
How to make last anchor color black?

I tried style below. back color appears only if mouse is over element. how to make link text black also if mouse is not over it ?

jquery jBreadCrumb from http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html is used to convert list to breadcrumb.
jquery, jquery-ui, ASP.NET MVC2 are used.

html:

```
<div id="breadCrumb" class="breadCrumb module">
<div style="overflow:hidden; position:relative; width: 990px;">
<div>
<ul style="width: 5000px;">
<li class="first">
<a href="/"></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/Store/Category?category=1">Level1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/Store/Category?category=28">level2</a>
</li>
<li class="last">
<a href="/Store/Browse?category=37521">level3shouldbeblack"</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.breadCrumb ul li.last, .last, .last:hover, .last:link, .last:visited, .last:active  {
    color:Black !important;
}
```

**Update**

I added `li:last-child` but problem persists. Below is contents from FireBug Sytle tab.
For unknow reasonblack colo appear only if mouse is hover last anchor text.
How to make last anchor text black always ?

```
.breadCrumb ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.breadCrumb ul li.last, .last, .last:hover, .last:link, .last:visited, .last:active {
    color: Black !important;
}
.breadCrumb ul li {
    font-size: 0.9167em;
    line-height: 21px;
}
li:last-child {
    color: Black !important;
}
.breadCrumb ul li.last, .last, .last:hover, .last:link, .last:visited, .last:active {
    color: Black !important;
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `.last a {color:black;}`?

Comment: Your welcome. Will upload an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the *color* of the *anchor* in the **last** *list-item* , use :

```
.last a{
    color:black;
}
```

This would also work, using the [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3alast-child) selector:

```
li:last-child a{
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following css will fix the issue,

```
.last a{
    color:Black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tUuzn/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a `selected` css class and add that class to the last breadcrumb using jquery when the page is loaded?

```
.selected a { color: black; }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("li.last", $("#breadCrumb").addClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***:last-child*** selector

```
li:last-child
{
 color:Black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li.last a{color : black;}
li:last-child a{color : black;}
```